# Indexers and storage location

Tags: c#, .net

one of the restrictions on Indexers is that indexer does not define a storage location, So a value produced by an indexer cannot be passed as a ref or out parameter to a method.
I was wondering the array that we define for indexer isn't a storage location?

Comment: User-defined indexers are really _methods_, so it makes sense that you can't pass them as a `ref` like you could a field. Are you asking about having an array as a backing field that the indexer wraps, or how you can pass an `Array` element as a `ref` despite the above stipulation?

Comment: Because it's not actually an array. It's just syntactic sugar for getter and setter methods with 1 or more parameters. You can't pass `myObject.GetItem(7)` as a `ref` parameter.

Comment: thank you guys, I was wondering the array that we define for indexer isn't a storage location?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to break down each part of your question and try to help you out.

### Does Index Define a Location in Storage?

> one of the restrictions on Indexers is that indexer does not define a storage location

If saying is "a location somewhere in storage is not guaranteed to be abstractedly defined in the classes implementation of that index" then yes that is correct, abstractly you are defining a value at the Index of the value of your indexer, but that does not guarantee you are accessing a logical location (at an abstract level, at a low level everything has a location). Basically an index is a pretty way to represent a method that takes a value and returns a value a variable(s) that indicates location and using syntax of brackets, and the equal sign to determine which method to call (get or set). I feel like I am getting off topic but you can look up more info on index implementation on  [on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) But just like methods **you have to make it make sense**. Here is an example of failing at that making sense and also not having an actual location on the back end of the implementation.

### A Weird Example

```
public class MyClass
{

   private void Set(int i,string value)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Your Index:{0}\r\nSet Value:{1}",i,value);
   }

   public string this[int i]
   {
        get
        {
            if(i<0)
               return "less than zero"; 
            if(i==0)
               return "This is zero";
            else if(i==1)
               return "This is one";
            else if(i==2)
               return "this is two";
            else
               return "more than two";

        }
        set
        {
           //value is a key word in a setter
           //representing the value on you are attempting to set
           Set(i,value);
        }
    }
}
```

### Don't do this

Why you would want to do this I am not sure sure, but if you  did want to you could, indexers are just a nice way of expressing a method where it makes sense that it is acting as an index, such as in a Dictionary or a List, and while someone might try to argue that technically the getter in this example does it still makes no sense and shouldn't be using an index to express the method

### Can You Pass an Index by ref or out to a Method

> So a value produced by an indexer cannot be passed as a ref or out parameter to a method.

since the data you are accessing through the index is encapsulated in the class unless the class exposes a reference to that data you cannot accesses it, therefore you cannot use pass it as a ref or an out parameter in a method call for an indexer property, so we need to see if accessing the indexer exposes a location in memory

### Short Answer

No, the key words `ref` and `out` basically tell the IL to make the method take a memory address, `out` requiring the location in memory be assigned a new value, `ref` not requiring  a change but still allowing it to happen, since all indexes and properties are not supported in all languages in .NET they are implemented by changing the instructions in "get" and "set" into method calls, `ref` and `out` needs a location in memory of the passed variable, reduced to IL trying to treat a get/set of an indexer as an out variable is equivalent to trying to treat a method or a fresh variable as a `ref` or `out` parameter which is semantically invalid

### Long Answer

You cannot, the reason why is because you are calling a method when you use the indexer, say you have this as the method you want to a call

```
public void CreateNew(out object target)
{
    target = new object();
}
```

#### What is happening

When you call the CreateNew method at some level instructions:

1. Take CreateNew Instruction Location
2. Puts The Location of the variable passed to target into a parameter slot
3. Changes the value of the memory in the location to a place in the heap
           holding the object created by the "new object();" statement
4. Returns control

#### It Doesn't work with an indexer

An indexer is called in two cases

#### Get:

the indexer "Get" method appears where the object is indexed and is trying to be accessed. When this happens a method call is made to some method that represents your get method that has a signature like

```
 
ValueType _get_index_IndexType_ValueType( IndexType index)
```

so if the compiler resolved your call to this as the out parameter then it would be like trying to pass a reference to a variable that hasn't been assigned a location in memory yet. That is why it wouldn't work with the "Get" method and this was done by design as logically you cannot access a location in memory for a variable from the location in memory of an object.

#### Set:

The indexer "Set" method appears when the object is indexed and on the left hand side of an equal sign, internally it is replace with some method that represents your set method that has a signature like this

```
 
void _set_index_IndexType_ValueType(IndexType index, ValueType Value)
```

So if the call reduces to this it would be the same thing as trying to access the location in memory of a method call, this is not what we want, what we want to do is call the set method when giving a new variable to the index, and get when we are trying to access it. However by design this is not allowed, as you can easily do this on your own...

#### More Code

If this still doesn't make sense try thinking of the class below, where instead of having an indexer method we just use a Get and Set with an index

```
public class MyFooIndexableObject
{
    /* Note that "ValueType" and "IndexType" are 
     * just place holders for whatever type you
     * decide to make as your return type and 
     * index type respectively  
     *
     * Using a regular dictionary and an
     * extra variable to implement a default 
     * dictionary so it is not like the example 
     * is doing nothing.
     */
    private Dictionary _internalCollection;
    private readonly ValueType _defaultValue = new ValueType();
    public void FooSet(IndexType index, ValueType value)
    {
        if( index == null)
            //want to disallow index being null
            throw new NullArgumentException("index");

        if(_internalCollection==null)
            _internalCollection = new Dictionary();

        if ( value == null || value == _defaultValue )
           // want to remove it 
        {
            _internalCollection.Remove(index);
        }
        else
            _internalCollection[index]=value;
    }

    /* The Examples FooSet and FooGet 
     * would be similar method constructs to 
     * the ones made behind the scenes when 
     * you define the getter and setter for 
     * your indexed object 
     */

    public ValueType FooGet(IndexType index)
    {
        if( _internalCollection == null 
            || !_internalCollection.Contains(index) )
                return new _defaultValue;

        return _internalCollection[index];
    }

    public bool TryGetValueAtFirstNonDefault(out IndexType outIndex,  
                                              out ValueType outValue)
    {
        outParam = outIndex = null;

        if(_internalCollection!=null)
        {
            // no need to check we maintain this in the setter and getter
            var temp= _internalCollection.FirstOrDefault();
            if(temp!=null)
            {
                outParam = temp.Value;
                outIndex = temp.Key;
            }
        }
        return outParam != null;
    }

    private static void Swap( ref ValueType someRefParam, 
                       ref ValueType otherRefParam)
    {
        var temp = someRefParam;
        someRefParam = otherRefParam;
        otherRefParam = temp;
    }

    //use this instead
    public void SwapValueAtIndexes(IndexType index1, IndexType index2)
    {
        var temp = this.FooGet(index1);
        this.FooSet(index1, this.FooGet(index2) );
        this.FooSet(index2, temp);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var indexable = new MyFooIndexableObject();
        var index1 = new IndexType(0);
        var index2 = new IndexType(1);
        ValueType someValue;

        //do someValue = indexable[index1]
        someValue = indexable.FooGet(index1);

        //do indexable[index1] = new ValueType()
        indexable.FooSet(index1,new ValueType());

        //this does not make sense will not work
        //do Swap( out indexable[index1], out indexable[index2] )
        //just look how you would try to do this

        Swap( ref indexable.FooGet(index1), ref indexable.FooGet(index2));

        //Swap is looking for reference to a location in memory
        //but the method is returning the value of an object reference
        //which you can store in a variable with a location in memory
        //but has yet been assigned to one

        //Please note the whole idea of "location in memory" is abstract
        //it does not technically mean an actual location in physical 
        //memory but probably an abstraction handled by .NET,
        //don't try to hard to make sure you have the technical part 
        //100% correct, you are significantly detached from the metal
        //when coding at this level...the basic idea is the same
        //as physical memory locations on a machine

        //However, you can accomplish the same things that you would
        //want to accomplish with "out" and "ref" by creating methods
        //that take the indexed object and an index, such as the
        //SwapValueAtIndex method

        indexable.SwapValueAtIndex(index1,index2);

        //While precisely what SwapValueAtIndex does may
        //not translate to what Swap does logically
        //it is the same thing, which is good enough for us

    }
}
```

### But You Can...

Even though you can't get to the actual reference of the object you can pass the index and the indexed object to a method, this will effectively give you the same effect as a reference to the variable because you can access it using the index and the object that it is located in

```
public void Swap(MyIndexedObject o, string indexer, object newValue, 
                    ref object oldValue)
{
    if(o.Contains(indexer))
    {
        oldValue = o[indexer];
    }
    else
        oldValue = null;

    o[indexer]=newValue;
}

public bool TryGetValue(MyIndexedObject o, string index, out object value)
{
    value=null;
    if(o.Contains(index))
    { 
        value = o[value];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void TrySwapValue(MyIndexedObject o, string indexer1, string indexer2)
{
    object valHolder1=null,valHolder2=null;
    if(TryGetValue(o,indexer1, out valHolder1))
    {
        Swap(o, indexer2, valHolder1,ref valHolder2);
        o[indexer1] = valHolder2;
    }
}
```

### What that Means

As you can see you can logically use an index as a location (in a case where the indexed object implementation makes sense) if you have the object, that is where indexed objects make sense to use

### Other Options

If you still want a reference to an indexed object you can define a class that has an index and gets and sets the value of the object, in this you could include thing like a history

```
public class MyObject : Dictionary{}

public class MyPlaceHolder
{
    public MyPlaceHolder(string index, MyObject target)
    {
        Index = index;
        TargetObject = target;
    }

    public string Index {get; private set;}
    public MyObject TargetObject {get; private set;}

    public object Value 
    {
        get
        {   
           return TargetObject[Index];
         }
        set
        {    
            var prev = TargetObject[Index];
            TargetObject[Index] = value;
            _prevVals.Push(prev);
        }
    }

    private Stack _prevVals = new Stack();

    public bool UndoSet()
    { 
        if(!_preVals.Count() == 0)
        {
            Value._prevVals.Pop();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

### Is a Storage Location in Existence for an Index?

> I was wondering the array that we define for indexer isn't a storage location?

Yes that array is a location, but the index definition is not a direct reflection of that address. An index into an object is an abstraction of the the concept of an Index, which is something that allows you to access an object based on an index value you pass into it, it does not necessarily do that but it should, technically it could be a method that has nothing to do with a location but it shouldn't.

However the way the object does not expose the actual location underneath is correct, you are using encapsulation to hide the way the location specified by your index method, which is one of the reasons we have object oriented programming  **I don't care if 0 is a location at the level of the implementation as long as it makes sense when I use it**

### A Better Example of using an Index

I feel bad for only creating one example of an Indexed object that is actually awful and something hopefully no one ever mistakenly thinks is a good idea, so will show why it makes sense to hide location, this is the purpose behind the abstraction of an index

Let's say I want to make a double key dictionary, I know in some part of my code I am going to implement it, but I don't know how yet, if you have multiple people working so you don't want people to wait around while you code the class, so you can define the interface, and implement it while the other programmers work

```
public interface IMyDoubleStringDictionaryBase<T>
{
    T this[string index1, string value2]
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

### The First Implementation

You decide to make it using nested dictionaries, this is what you come up with

```
public class MyDoubleStringDictionary<T> : IMyDoubleStringDictionaryBase<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,T>> _baseCollection;

    public T this[string index1, string index2]
    {
        get
        {
            if(_baseCollection.ContainsKey(index1))
            {
                var nextDict = _baseCollection[index1];
                if(nextDict.ContainsKey(index2))
                {
                    return nextDict[index2];
                }
            }

            return default(T);
        }
        set
        {
            Dictionary<string,T> nextDict;
            if(_baseCollection.Contains(index1))
            {
                nextDict = _baseCollection[index1];
            }
            else
            {
                nextDict = new Dictionary<string,T>();
                _baseCollection.Add(index1,nextDict);
            }

            nextDict[index2] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### You Have a Problem

For some reason the Dictionary class is not available to you in your production environment, while this might not make sense to you you are told to make one using only the Array data structure, all other abstract data structures you need to define yourself. You decide to make a bucket hash that takes the two hashes of the keys and mixes them

```
public class MyNewDoubleStringDictionary<T> : IMyDoubleStringDictionaryBase<T>
{
    private class Node<T>
    {
        public Node<T> Next;
        public string Key1,Key2;
        public T Value;
    }

    private const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1024;
    private Node<T>[] _internalCollection = new Node<T>[ARRAY_SIZE];

    private int GetIndex(string key1, string key2)
    {
        const int key1mask = 0x0F0F0F0F;
        const int key2mask = 0xF0F0F0F0;
        var key1 = key1mask & key1.GetHashCode();
        var key2 = key2mask & key2.GetHashCode();
        var result = ((key1 | key2) & 0x7FFFFFFF)% ARRAY_SIZE;
        return result;
    }

    private Node<T> GetOrMakeNode(string key1,string key2)
    {
       int index = GetIndex(key1,key2);
       Node<T> currNode=_internalCollection[index];

       if(currNode == null)
       {
           _internalCollection[index] = currNode = new Node<T>();
        }
        else
       {
           while(!(currNode.Key1.Equals(key1)
                    &&currNode.Key2.Equals(key2))
               if(currNode.Next!=null)
               {
                  currNode = currNode.Next;
               }
               else
               {
                 currNode.Next = new Node<T>();
                 currNode = currNode.Next;
               }
       }
       if(currNode.Key1 == null || currNode.Key2 == null)
       {
           currNode.Key1 = key1;
           currNode.Key2 = key2;
       }
       return currNode;
    }

    public this[string index1, string index2]
    {
        get
        {
           var node = GetOrMakeNode(index1,index2);
           return node.Value;
        }
        set
        {
           var node = GetOrMakeNode(index1,index2);
           node.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

#### The Result

Even though you had a change in requirements and implementation it did not interrupt any of your team's work, because you aren't making references to internal workings of objects so it would be impossible for it to mess up their work.

### Why it Makes Sense

You don't care where the location is, you shouldn't really be worried if the actual implementation is looking at a location just know that you have to interface the index in a certain way and you will be able to use it

Comment: Wow... Epic... One thing that I think is confusing though is that in your "But You Can..." section you pass a `MyIndexedObject o` parameter. You then call `o.Contains` which implies that any Indexed object has a `Contains` method which isn't true.

Comment: I wasn't saying that, I was just implying that this particular object did have a `Contains` method, just so I was doing something else besides indexing the captured object

Comment: Wow what a huge answer, deserves a award!

Comment: @FelixK. I think I made it too long, having trouble making fixes to it. Fix something in one place, forget to fix it in another like using the wrong term or whatever... I really like this type of stuff though, so I didn't even notice until I was done how long it was

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx

Indexer are just special getters and setters. And ref or out are always just local variables. Indexer doesn't even have to point to a storage location but can return computed values.

Indexer don't even have to be used on arrays. For example in a vector image i could define indexers myvectorimage[x][y] such that it returns the color at a x and y location but the data is never stored that way.

Comment: Just a minor note: `ref` and `out` can also be used for fields in addition to local variables.